# regex to get measurements

Tags: python, regex, units-of-measurement

I have these measurements in the document

```
5.3 x 2.5 cm
11 x 11 mm
7 mm 
13 x 12 x 14 mm
13x12cm
```

I need to extract 5.3 x 2.5 cm using python using regex.

So far my code is below but it does not work properly

```
x = "\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,4}\.?\d{0,2}|\d{5}\.?\d?|\d{6}\.?"
by = "( )?(by|x)( )?"
cm = "(mm|cm|millimeter|centimeter|millimeters|centimeters)"
x_cm = "((" + x + " *(to|\-) *" + cm + ")" + "|(" + x + cm + "))"
xy_cm = "((" + x + cm + by + x + cm + ")" +"|(" + x + by + x + cm + ")" +"|(" + x + by + x + "))"
xyz_cm = "((" + x + cm + by + x + cm + by + x + cm + ")" + "|(" + x + by + x + by + x + cm + ")" + "|(" + x + by + x + by + x + "))"
m = "((" + xyz_cm + ")" + "|(" + xy_cm + ")" + "|(" + x_cm + "))"
a = re.compile(m)
print a.findall(text)
```

The output it gives:

```
[('13', '13', '13', '13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''), ('12', '12', '12', '12', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''), ('4', '4', '4', '4', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''), ('25', '25', '25', '25', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''),
```

Comment: Define "does not work properly": what *does* it do vs. what *should* it do?  Examples would be most welcome.

Comment: Please show and explain the difference between the output you get and the output you want.

Comment: One thing you must do is to get rid of capturing groups. However, you should check the [final pattern](https://regex101.com/r/LcTavz/1) after concatenation, it only [returns numbers only](https://ideone.com/TOX9eK).

Comment: Check the helpfulness for your goal of "noncapturing groups" `(?:blabla)`, it might be helpful for incorporating Wiktors comment.

Comment: Thank you very much @WiktorStribiżew it was so fast and solved most of my problem. Ultimately my goal is extracting all measurements in the text, therefore I need to extract their units too. My plan was extract everything as a string like  "5.3 x 2.5 cm". 1) Does it make sense? and 2) How can I do that, any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only issues with the current regex are two:

- You need to get rid of capturing groups since `.findall` will extract all the substrings captured rather than the whole match value (however, it is not crucial, you might as well use `re.finditer` and get `match.group(0)`)
- The main issue is that you did not group the `x` pattern, the number format alternation ruined the structure of the final pattern.

A quick fix will look like

```
x = "(?:\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,4}\.?\d{0,2}|\d{5}\.?\d?|\d{6}\.?)"
by = "(?: )?(?:by|x)(?: )?"
cm = "(?:mm|cm|millimeter|centimeter|millimeters|centimeters)"
x_cm = "(?:" + x + " *(?:to|\-) *" + cm + "|" + x + cm + ")"
xy_cm = "(?:" + x + cm + by + x + cm +"|" + x + by + x + cm +"|" + x + cm + by + x +"|" + x + by + x + ")"
xyz_cm = "(?:" + x + cm + by + x + cm + by + x + cm + "|" + x + by + x + by + x + cm + "|" + x + by + x + by + x + ")"
m = "{}|{}|{}".format(xyz_cm, xy_cm, x_cm)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/yw4KB4) printing

```
['5.3 x 2.5', '11 x 11', '13 x 12 x 14', '13x12cm']
```

To further enhance it, think of all possibilities of `x`, `by`, `cm` and perhaps use `str.format` instead of concatenation.

Answer (score 7):

With Regex you should always slowly build up your expression to get what you want. E.g.

```
s = "5.3 x 2.5 cm"
```

You want to find the numbers here?

```
re.findall("\d+", s)
```

gives you all the integers:

```
["5", "3", "2", "5"]
```

Ok, so what if your numbers can be floating point but don't have to be. Then you expand your expression with a non-capturing match group that has a dot and maybe some numbers following.

```
re.findall("\d+(?:\.\d*)?", s)
```

this gives you

```
["5.3", "2.5"]
```

Then you can take the multiplication with an arbitrary number of spaces around:

```
re.findall("(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)\s*x\s*(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)", s)
```

Putting the numbers in match groups now gives you a tuple.

```
[("5.3", "2.5")]
```

You can then go on with the units:

```
re.findall("(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)\s*x\s*(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)\s*(cm|mm)", s)
```

giving you the tuple you want:

```
[("5.3", "2.5", "cm")]
```

and so on.

If you build your regexes like this you have a chance to see what breaks from one change to the next. Debugging a huge regex like the one you posted above is a task not worth going at.

I wouldn't name my unit regex as `cm` that's quite confusing for anyone maintaining your code in the future. Apart from that you need some clear requirements on the number formats you want to allow. Maybe somebody will input scientific notation etc. Your regexes will become very complicated.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem! Also extra thanks for all of your detailed explanation!!!

Comment: The only thing it does not find when there is only one measure (7 mm ) but I will figure it out.

Comment: @user1979556 I think that can be left as an exercise to the reader ;-).

Comment: but still, I could not make it :)